# How to create video clips using a data frame of file names, start and end times?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

This questions has been edited to streamline the specific question that I developed with help from users here. (thanks)

I have a data frame with file paths, identifiers and start and stop times. I am trying to loop through each row of this data frame and create video clips using ffmpeg.

The data frame is like this:

```
Time    File_path   Behavior    Status  experiment_id   Start_time  Stop_time   Duration
130 314.287 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_05   312.787 315.787 3.0
145 784.158 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_05   782.658 785.658 3.0
140 708.906 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_05   707.406 710.406 3.0
33  507.600 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_02   506.100 509.100 3.0
75  112.690 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_03   111.190 114.190 3.0
133 344.057 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_05   342.557 345.557 3.0
26  366.215 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_02   364.715 367.715 3.0
70  84.448  H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_03   82.948  85.948  3.0
113 738.897 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_03   737.397 740.397 3.0
128 200.548 H:/My Drive/Katz-Lab_Otter-Data/Projects/Forag...   Scrunch POINT   K8_feed_111120_05   199.048 202.048 3.0
```

The goal is to use the video specified by the File_path to make a video clip using the time stamps specified and create an output file that uses a specified variable `ouput_path` and appends the last 18 or so characters of the `File_path` and the  `Behavior`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#loop through the lines of the data frame
for row in sampled_data.index:
    
    #print(sampled_data["File_path"][row]) 
    
    output_file = ("%(path)s\%(experiment_id)s_%(behavior)s_%(index)s.MP4" 
                   % {"path" : output_path, 
                      "experiment_id" : sampled_data["experiment_id"][row], 
                      "behavior" : sampled_data["Behavior"][row],
                      "index" : row})
    
    #print(output_file)
    
    subprocess.check_call([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-ss', str(sampled_data["Start_time"][row]),
        '-i', str(sampled_data["File_path"][row]),
        '-t', str(sampled_data["Duration"][row]),
        '-c', 'copy', 
        output_file])
```

Edit: I got it to work!

Comment: syntax issue. backslashes in a string literal have special meaning. -- ffmpeg returns with "non-zero exit status", so it did run, but didn't like the argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#loop through the lines of the data frame
for row in sampled_data.index:
    
    #print(sampled_data["File_path"][row]) 
    
    output_file = ("%(path)s\%(experiment_id)s_%(behavior)s_%(index)s.MP4" 
                   % {"path" : output_path, 
                      "experiment_id" : sampled_data["experiment_id"][row], 
                      "behavior" : sampled_data["Behavior"][row],
                      "index" : row})
    
    #print(output_file)
    
    subprocess.check_call([
        'ffmpeg',
        '-ss', str(sampled_data["Start_time"][row]),
        '-i', str(sampled_data["File_path"][row]),
        '-t', str(sampled_data["Duration"][row]),
        '-c', 'copy', 
        output_file])
```

This works if there are no spaces in the file name! Also in order to specify the output path it works if you fully create the path and file name then pass to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on the part you probably have the most trouble with: the video manipulation.

It's probably easiest to use Python's `subprocess` module and run subprocesses of `ffmpeg` for this.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([
    'ffmpeg',
    '-ss', str(starttime),
    '-i', inputfilepath,
    '-t', str(duration),
    '-c', 'copy', # alternatively -c:v mjpeg -q:v 2
    outputfilepath])
```

You can tell ffmpeg to [start decoding the input at a specific time (`-ss {timecode}` before/after](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) `-i {the input file}`), and read a specific amount of time from the video (`-t {duration}`). The rest is just encoder parameters.

If your input video is intra-only coded, you could even `-c copy` the data with *no loss* of quality. Just mentioning that in case it's important.

Comment: I don't think I need to use subprocesses for this.

Comment: you don't think so? what would you use then? something more complicated than a simple execution of ffmpeg?

Comment: My last edit is what I am trying to do. I'm hoping it wont need to be that complicated.

Comment: my answer shows how to invoke ffmpeg as a subprocess. I don't see the issue.

Comment: because python isn't shell scripting, and even a shell script would start a subprocess. you can't just type stuff that isn't python syntax, and expect python to understand it.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now, I have streamlined the question with this knowledge. I did not know what subprocessing was and why it would be needed in this case.